# Subtheme install settings in config but not showing

Tags: bootstrap-theme

In a brand new site installation, I created a subtheme of the Bootstrap theme. In the subtheme (let's call "mytheme") config/install/mytheme.settings.yml file, I have the following settings.

```
settings:
  navbar_position: 'fixed-top'
  onelab_footer_type: Fat
  cdn_provider: custom
  cdn_custom_css: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css'
  cdn_custom_css_min: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  cdn_custom_js: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js'
  cdn_custom_js_min: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

I have verified that the database config table shows these settings. However, these settings are not getting applied. I have cleared the cache and that doesn't seem to do anything either. So, if they are correctly in the config table, how do I get Drupal to apply them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the documentation shows to place the settings under the "settings" key, I was then told to put it at the top level without the settings key. That is working.